# String characters replacement PHP

Tags: php, string, preg-replace, str-replace

I am very close to solving the problem, however I can't figure out how to remove whitespaces that surround the string. Eg: `' ! '`, `'! '`, and `' !'` become `'!'`. And this applies to the ? character, . character and other punctuation characters.

Here is my code so far. It is supposed to take characters and convert them to nato words which I have done, but my punctuation is wrong. Eg `' ! awesome. .! '` turns to `' ! Alfa Whiskey Echo Sierra Oscar Mike Echo . . !'` when I dont want whitespaces between the punctuations.

```
function to_nato($words){
    $key = array("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z");
    $translationKey = array("Alfa", "Bravo", "Charlie", "Delta", "Echo", "Foxtrot", "Golf", "Hotel", "India", "Juliet", "Kilo", "Lima", "Mike", "November", "Oscar", "Papa", "Quebec", "Romeo", "Sierra", "Tango", "Uniform", "Victor", "Whiskey", "Xray", "Yankee", "Zulu");
    $strToRet = "";
    for($i = 0; $i < strlen($words); $i++) {
        $letter = substr($words, $i, 1);
        if(ctype_alpha($letter)) {
            for($keySearch = 0; $keySearch < count($key); $keySearch++) {
                $letterToSearch = array_search($key[$keySearch], $key);
                if(strcasecmp($letter, $key[$letterToSearch]) == 0) {
                    $natoLetter = $translationKey[$letterToSearch];
                    $strToRet .= $natoLetter;
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            $strToRet .= $letter;
        }
    }
    $strToRet = preg_replace('/([a-z])([A-Z])/s','$1 $2', $strToRet);
    //$strToRet = str_replace(" ! ", "!", $strToRet, $count);
    return $strToRet;
}
```

Comment: Not related to the problem, but you should use an associative array instead of two arrays to find the letter mappings.

Comment: I tried your function, I don't get extra spaces before the punctuations. The only spaces around the punctuation are the ones that were in the original string.

Comment: I get `" ! Alfa Whiskey Echo Sierra Oscar Mike Echo. .! "`

Comment: I want to use some sort of loop and remove those exact spaces. I get those spaces using the preg replace but i dont want them to surround the punctuation symbols

Comment: What's the point of `$letterToSearch = array_search($key[$keySearch], $key);`? Isn't `$letterToSearch` the same as `$keySearch`?

Comment: Why don't you just remove all spaces from the input string? Do you need some of them to be copied to the output?

Comment: This is the condition i need to pass: Failed asserting that two strings are equal.
Expected: 'Uniform Foxtrot!Victor Alfa'
Actual  : 'Uniform Foxtrot ! Victor Alfa'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the spaces around punctuation from the original string:

```
$words = preg_replace('/\s*([^\w\s]+)\s*/', '$1', $words);
```

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/LoqZVJ)

Comment: your solution results in `!AlfaWhiskeyEchoSierraOscarMikeEcho..!` which is not what the topicstarter wants as I understand :)

Comment: I want it to pass a test case such as this: Failed asserting that two strings are equal.
Expected: '.Yankee'
Actual  : '. Yankee'

Comment: @KaranGoda I've added a demo showing that it works correctly. There are spaces between each of the phonetic letters.

Comment: Could there be something wrong with codewars? Because it fails in there

Comment: @Barmar I tried here http://www.writephponline.com/ and the result was different. Maybe different php versions / settings? On the site you gave it works indeed, sorry.

Comment: His regex is giving me 'SierraZuluCharlieEchoVictorOscar'

Comment: Actually my bad both of you...it was another condition entirely and i just had to trim the ends. Thank you both for contributing, it was only after seeing another perspective i realised this. @curveball

Comment: Please see above comment @barmar

Comment: I get the same result at writephponline.com. If you just need to trim spaces at the ends, use `trim($strToRet)`.

Comment: Do you use some sort of software for the regex requirements? Some of them can get really complex.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change this `if(ctype_alpha($letter)` to this `if(ctype_alpha($letter) || $letter==" ")`. I could get rid of that space in the result (using the input string you provided in the description).